# Application misconfigured

Tags: android, google-signin

I am developing an app where you are supposed to login with your Google account.

Last week I developed it on my Mac and it worked fine login in. Now I have changed to my desktop computer since I like it more. However, although I have updated the credentials with `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore` and configured the project [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) it does not work.

I always get `error code 10` and cannot login. Does anyone have a clue where to search for the error?

The error is on my device and the path and files should be correct. I have followed the instructions from Google to get the debug keys.

Can it be blocked for some reason since I have changed computer?

I "solved" it by starting a new project. Google requires a different key for different computers and it seems troublesome to just update the keys. Does anyone have a good idea of how to smoothly go between computers and only work on one project? Having two projects and a symbolic link to the source code?